# wp7 navigating between a page and a pivot, do i always need to reload pivot items?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have developed an app that has a pivot with pivot items where http links are listed (visualized through images) and a page with a webbrowser control. When i select a link it is displayed in the webbrowser. Now I have the problem when i return to the pivot the pivot items are empty that i need to load them again.

So my question is this the standard, expected behaviour? The reason i'm asking I'm not using the mvvm model and my items inside the pivot items are displayed through user controls.

My second question, do you have any idea how i can prevent reloading it? I tried already to  make the webbrowser as popup, but i dont have the required appbar available. Probably is there a way to cache or retieve the pivot?

Any idea is welcome.

Regards, 
 Ralf

Comment: In which method you are loading pivot items?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, after navigating away from Pivot Page, I reloaded the items in the `OnNavigatedTo` function of the pivot page.

But I did few optimizations like, I had a cached the static data so that I dont have to load them every time from my IsolatedStorage, hence faster loading of the page.
I had lots of images which were loaded to `ImageBrushes` in the constructor so that I avoid assigning them every time.

Comment: Hi alfah, i just read an article about Page_Loaded and OnNavigatedTo event, after changing method from Page_Loaded and OnNavigatedTo i have the feeling it is a little bit faster at least on the emulator. I will check now on the device. Thanks!

Comment: @Raif, Glad I could help. If you have solved the problem, please mark the answer and close the topic.